# Runtime array bounds on stack as per c++ draft

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, g++, runtime

As per my understanding  based on previous readings, array size needs to be constant and known at compile time with exception to additional support provided by g++ where VLA are supported.

However I was going through one of the c++ draft and now I am confused, does c++ support runtime array bounds. They have given the below code example for defining the array.

C++ draft link: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf

Section 8.3.4

Eg:

```
void f(unsigned int n) {
int a[n]; // type of a is “array of runtime bound of int”
}
```

Comment: Don't refer to outdated standard drafts. The closest drafts to the published standards can be found on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links) or [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C++ has not and still doesn't support arrays with a run time size.  N3690 was a draft between C++11 and C++14 and it included the text from the propsal [N3639 Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage duration (revision 5)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html)

That proposal was eventually scrapped and in the [C++14 draft N4140](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/draft.pdf) the text was removed.

When looking through the drafts, the ones that you can use as "The standard" are

- [N3337](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/draft.pdf) (C++11 + editorial fixes)
- [N4140](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/draft.pdf) (C++14 + editorial fixes)
- [N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/draft.pdf) (March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS)